# Media module to select images from flickr, copy them locally?

Tags: 7, media, files

All our photos are on flickr. I'd like a **user friendly** way so that a content editor can select an image from flickr and use it on a page, e.g. in an image field.

I've used Media 2.x before which works fine for offering the user a selection mechanism for images, and to upload new ones.

I'd like that to include a browser for flickr images from our flickr account, and when the content editor chooses one, the original image should be downloaded from flickr and imported to Drupal, just as it would if the user had provided an image from their computer.

I've looked at [media_flickr](https://drupal.org/project/media_flickr) but this does not seem to be offering what I'm after. I looked at [flickrsync](https://drupal.org/project/flickrsync) but this is no longer maintained/developed for D7. Same story for [flickrriper](https://drupal.org/project/flickrrippr).

Has anyone done this? Is "there a module for that" which I've missed?

Comment: I hope you know that it may be illegal to do so? "Many Flickr users have chosen to offer their work under a Creative Commons license, and you can browse or search through content under each type of license." ([source](http://www.flickr.com/creativecommons/)) - but not all. As far as I can see, none of the abandoned modules cared. Also, modules rarely provide whole functionality you need, especially it's overly optimistic to expect their interpretation of "user friendly" will be the same as yours.

Comment: I said I want it to browse images from **our account**. We let ourselves use our own photos ;-)

Comment: [flickrgallery](https://drupal.org/project/flickrgallery) provides a selection mechanism, so perhaps I'm looking for a way to bridge that with Media 2...

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear ;) I meant that your situation may be perfectly legitimate, but generic modules are generic ;) so it can lead to some licensing problems.

Comment: Most flickr modules require API keys, obviously these are non-generic. API access to an account is via Oauth; the user must have given authority. So there's a fairly broad case of "authorised access to photos" here.